# Make overlines in Python

Tags: python, string, unicode

Hello my fellow coders!

I'm an absolute beginner to Python and coding in general. Right now, I'm writing a code that converts regular arabic numerals to roman. For numbers larger than 3 999, the romans usually wrote a line over a letter to make it thousand times larger. For example, IV with a line over it represented 4 000. How is this possible in Python? I have understood that you can create an "overscore" by writing "\u203E". How can I make this appear over a letter instead of beside it?

Regards

Comment: Please post the code you've tried so far so that we can play with it and give you an answer!

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the combining character U+0304 instead.

```
>>> print(u'a\u0304')
ā
```

U+0305 is probably a better choice (as viraptor suggests). You can also use the Unicode Roman numerals (U+2160 through U+217f) instead of regular uppercase Latin letters, although (at least in my terminal) they don't render as well with the overline.

```
>>> print(u'\u2163\u0305')
Ⅳ̅
>>> print u'I\u0305V\u0305'
I̅V̅
```

(Or as I see it:

[image]

Notice the overline is centered over, but does not completely cover, the single-character Roman numeral 4.)

(Any pure text option will only be as good as the font and renderer used by the person running the code. Case in point, the I+V version does not even display consistently while I type this; sometimes the overbars are over the letters, sometimes they follow the letters.)

Comment: This does not pair well with uppercase letters which are needed for romaen numerals

Comment: It doesn't pair well with multiple characters either. Plain text (even Unicode) simply doesn't handle all typesetting needs.

Comment: Almost - a combining overline is 305 and it works quite well with "IV" - `u'I\u0305V\u0305'` (gives I̅V̅)

Comment: Ironically, that looks better (at least with my terminal's font) than `u'\u2163\u0305'`, which uses the actual Unicode code point for Roman numeral IV.

Comment: While practicality may dictate otherwise, the *proper* solution is to use the Unicode glyphs with the correct *semantics,* and wait for font renderers to catch up and make it pretty.

Comment: I'm not sure that much thought went into the semantics of this Unicode block, though. Numbers 1 through 12 each have an assigned code point, but it seems the reason for stopping at 12 was simply because 1-12 along with 50, 100, 500, and 1000 formed a set of 16.

Comment: Thank you all for very fast replies! I can't get this to work however... Sorry for my stupidity. If I use u'I\u0305V\u0305' the lines will come after each letter. If I instead use u'I\u0304V\u0304' the "I" will have the "small" overscore over it but the "V" will just have the overscore after the letter.

Comment: u'\u2163\u0304' doesn't work either. Which is quite weird since the I in u'I\u0304V\u0304' is overscored.

Okay, this is really weird. u304 ONLY works with the letter "I". For V, X, L or anything else, the line just appears beside the letter.

Comment: Like I said, it depends on your font and your renderer.

Answer (score 2):

A combining overline is `\u305` and it works quite well with "IV". What you want is for example: `u'I\u0305V\u0305'` (gives I̅V̅)

Answer (score 0):

I looked for something online but didn't find it. The best workaround I'd suggest would be the following:

```
def over(character):
    return "_\n"+character
```

Such as:

```
>>> print over("M")
_
M
>>>
```

Comment: This solution works in some cases but is problematic for multiple characters in a row.

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this answer is `rich`

Install it by running

```
pip install rich
```

and then use in code like

```py
from rich import print  # or  from rich import print as rprint

print('[o]123[/]') # o for outline
```